# Can I plug a regular distortion pedal in front of a Zoom G5 multi-effects?

Tags: guitar-effects, electronics

I'm wondering if I'm risking some kind of electrical damage while plugging a regular disto pedal (or other kinds of gain pedals) on the guitar input of a multi effect expecting a passive/active guitar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happened to the sense of adventure? I'm picturing Jimi Hendrix wondering whether putting a fuzz box in front of his Marshall might hurt it… deciding not to & depriving the world...

Comment: @tetsujin Any interesting anecdotes on that :P?

Comment: And failing the sense of adventure, what happened to reading the manual: https://zoomcorp.com/media/documents/G5_operationManual_english.pdf? (P5 might give you a clue...)

Comment: @Tom - 'fraid not ;) Closest I ever got to a Hendrix story is I once drove past the pub in Clonakilty that Noel Redding was playing at… not really one to write home about, in the overall scheme of things ;) https://www.thejournal.ie/de-barras-clonakilty-3915699-Mar2018/

Comment: @Tetsujin I would have tryied If I stayed unto in analogic path but ever since I burned 2 usb / jack Cable putting them on the output bypassed of the G5 so ...

Comment: I thought "this is the switch to use if you want to use a pedal on the input" was pretty clear

Comment: Guess I haven't read it all, I expected that setting active was the way but I wasn't sure it was enough for a disto gain, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @DavidW could you formulate it as an answer so I can validate it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 5 of [the manual](https://zoomcorp.com/media/documents/G5_operationManual_english.pdf) says that about the "active/passive" switch:

> set  this  to  “ACTIVE”  (pushed  in)  if you  have  an  effect  pedal  connected between your instrument and the G5 or you are directly connecting a guitar with active pickups

Therefore I think it's fine to have an effects pedal in front of it.

In the troubleshooting section it mentions using this switch if "the sound distorts strangely" suggesting that the likely consequence for having it set wrong is a bit of unwanted distortion (i.e. it probably won't break the G5, but may sound a bit bad)

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with plugging in an effect pedal in front of such multi-effect pedal.

Note however that a digital effect might have a limited input range, so you may end up clipping the multi-effect input if you try to use overdrive pedal to boost the input signal, similarly to how people do in front of real amps. But again, it's unlikely to damage anything.